# Atlanta Sitecore User Group - November 21, 2019 

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**Date/Time (EST):** November 21, 2019 6:30 p.m.

**Date/Time (UTC):** November 21, 2019, 23:30

**Location:** [Roam Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us), 3365 Piedmont Rd NE, Suite 1400, Atlanta, GA

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Sitecore/events/265047614/

**Twitter:** [@AtlantaSitecore](https://twitter.com/atlantasitecore)

[image: Atlanta Sitecore User Group]

Mark your calendars for the next Atlanta Sitecore User Group meeting on Thursday, November 21st, at 6:30 p.m., at [Roam in Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us)!

Parking will be complimentary. We will be providing prepaid validations to all our guests. Dinner and drinks will be served.

We are looking forward to a great meeting! Everyone is welcome and we encourage you to spread the word!

### Raffle

Once again, [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) has provided us with a [ReSharper Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotnet/) license to give away. At the end of the event, we will raffle off the license along with other Sitecore goodies.

### Agenda

- 6:30 – 6:50: Food, drinks and social time
- 6:50 – 7:00: [Martin English](https://twitter.com/martinrenglish) ([Focus Brands](https://www.focusbrands.com/)) - Sitecore Community Update
- 7:00 – 7:35: [Varun Nehra](https://twitter.com/sitecorevarun) ([Altudo](https://www.altudo.co/)) - Marketing personalized at scale: Sitecore + SFMC = success
- 7:40 – 8:15: [Scott Stocker](https://twitter.com/sestocker) ([Perficient Digital](https://www.perficientdigital.com/)) - Reinventing a modern intranet for a global professional services organization
- 8:15: Closing comments, end of event

### Presentations

#### Marketing personalized at scale: Sitecore + SFMC = success

**Speaker**: [Varun Nehra](https://twitter.com/sitecorevarun) ([Altudo](https://www.altudo.co/))

Marketers need speed. From identifying prospects to creating segmentation, from creating customer profiles to personalizing campaigns, and from creating contextual content to launching campaigns at scale, marketers need agility and accuracy. Sitecore Connect allows marketers to break data silos, integrate their experience and marketing platforms, and create a single view of customers to achieve faster time to market.

#### Reinventing a modern intranet for a global professional services organization

**Speaker**: [Scott Stocker](https://twitter.com/sestocker) ([Perficient Digital](https://www.perficientdigital.com/))

Due to increased business demand, Orrick’s intranet experienced tremendous growth as it expanded to thousands of pages, reports, and business applications. The firm didn’t have a centralized content management system or an integrated search platform and needed a quicker and more efficient way of managing and distributing information to meet its employee and client needs. Orrick also has both an externally facing website and separate fully functioning intranet built on Sitecore 9, for a comprehensive web strategy that reduces internal training time and allows for efficient tracking and sharing of content within and beyond the company.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Oct 14 at 23:30